Approximate perimeter in terms of limits of area
I would like to know whether it is possible to find an expression for the perimeter in terms of some limits of area. Let me be more precise.
Suppose that $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is a set of finite perimeter, that is, the distribution $|D \chi_E|$ belongs to the space $BV$ of functions with bounded variation. Then $P(E)= \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\Gamma)$ where $d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ is the Hausdorff measure, and $ \Gamma = \partial ^\ast E$ is the reduced boundary of $E$. Suppose also that $E$ is compact and contained in some ball $B$.
My first candidate is to consider the neighborhoods $I_t$ defined by
$$ I_t = I_t (\Gamma)= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \mathrm{dist} (x ,\partial ^\ast E) < t \}$$
for small $t>0$, and compute the Lebesgue measures $|I_t|$ for example by means of the coarea formula. Is it true that the limit of volumes $$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{t} |I_t|$$ is, by some modifications, proportional to the perimeter $P(E)$? Is the smoothness of the set $E$  necessary here?
Any suggestions and comments are welcomed.

I put formulas between two $. But they don't appear as correct latex codes. Hope anybody can see the corrects formulas!

You forgot a $ :).

@HackR Thanks for editing!
